# Question on Permutation and Combinations. 6 people are to be accommodated in 4 hotel rooms, provided each room has at least 1 person and Max 2.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Complete Question:
In a hotel, four rooms are available. Six persons are to be accommodated in these four rooms in such a way  that each of these rooms contains at least one person and at most two persons. Then the number of all  possible ways in which this can be done is?

I am not getting answer using my method, kindly tell me where am I going wrong:
Number of ways of selecting 4 people out of 6= 15.
Now arranging those 4 people in 4 rooms= 4!=24
Now remaining 2 people.
To select any 2 random rooms out of 4= 6ways
Now arranging the 2 people in 2 rooms is 6ways * 2= 12.
So final answer according to me: 15 * 24 * 12= 4320.
But the correct answer given in the solution is 1080. Where am I going wrong please explain.
[image: my solution]

Comment: You seriously overcount. For example if persons A,B ended up in room 1, then you counted this configuration a few times: first when person A was among the 4 chosen initially and person B among the other two, and then also the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange the six people in a queue (6!). Arrange the rooms ($1122. 1212, 1221. 2112, 2121, 2211$ - $6$ ways). This gives $4320$ ways.

But there are two rooms with two people, and so these can be removed as duplicates $2\times2$ ways, so $1080$ ways in all.

Comment: Didn't get that. Which duplicates are you talking about?

Comment: @Daksh; assume a room pattern. say $1122$. Then arrange the people $6!$ ways, and place them into the rooms in the order $1122$. In this pattern $123456,123465, 124356, 124365$ are all the same,

Comment: Yeah got this, but how my solution is making the same mistake? Can you explain in which step am I going wrong? I have posted img of my solution too

Comment: @Daksh; if the 4 people you pick are 1234 and then 56, you get the same result as 5634 with 12.

Comment: But people aren't identical.

Comment: @Daksh I think this answer is right. Choose a particular queue for 6 people, eg. CFADBE. Choose the rooms occupancy, eg. 1-2-1-2. Then we put people according to their queue position, ie C goes to first room, F and A go to second room, D goes to third room, B and E go to fourth room. There are 6! x 6 = 4320 ways to do this. Are there overcounting? Yes, because if the queue had been CAFDEB, the room assignment would be exactly the same, ie C goes to first room, A and F go to second room, D goes to third room, E and B go to fourth room. The number of overcounting is 4 fold. So we divide by 4.

Comment: @James got you. I understand what you are trying to say. Can you please point out the same mistake in my solution? Btw thank you both of you guys

Answer (score 2):

Since six people must be distributed to four rooms, each room must receive at least one person, and no room may receive more than two people, two of the four rooms must receive two people each, while the other two rooms receive one person each.  Suppose the rooms are numbered from 1 to 4.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the two rooms which will each receive two people.  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select which two people will be placed in the lower-numbered of those two rooms, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select which two people will be placed in the higher-numbered of those two rooms, and $2!$ ways to arrange the remaining two people in the two rooms that will each receive a single person.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$$
possible distributions of six people to four rooms if each room is to receive at least one person and no room is to receive more than two people.

*Why is your answer incorrect?*

By designating a particular person to be the person in a given room, you count each distribution four times, twice each for each of the two ways you could designate one of the two people in the two rooms that receive two people as the person in that room.

To illustrate, consider the distribution in which Angela and Barbara are placed in room 1, Clara and Deirdre are placed in room 2, Elisabeth is placed in room 3, and Fiona is placed in room 4.  You count this distribution four times.

\begin{array}{6}
\text{room 1} & \text{room 2} & \text{room 3} & \text{room 4} & \text{additional person in room 1} & \text{additional person in room 2}\\ \hline
\text{Angela} & \text{Clara} & \text{Elisabeth} & \text{Fiona} & \text{Barbara} & \text{Deirdre}\\
\text{Angela} & \text{Deirdre} & \text{Elisabeth} & \text{Fiona} & \text{Barbara} & \text{Clara}\\
\text{Barbara} & \text{Clara} & \text{Elisabeth} & \text{Fiona} & \text{Angela} & \text{Deirdre}\\
\text{Barbara} & \text{Deirdre} & \text{Elisabeth} & \text{Fiona} & \text{Angela} & \text{Clara} 
\end{array}